# How to replay a one shot animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to make a one shot animation but be able to play it as many times as I want. Right now it plays only the first time.

.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/p1_ch1" android:oneshot="true">
    <item 
      android:drawable="@drawable/p1_ch1_5" 
      android:duration="500"/>
    <item 
      android:drawable="@drawable/p1_ch1_4" 
      android:duration="1000"/>
    <item 
      android:drawable="@drawable/p1_ch1_5" 
      android:duration="500"/>
</animation-list>
```

.java:

```
public void handler_p1_ch1_5 (View target){
      ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.p1_ch1_5);
      AnimationDrawable aw = (AnimationDrawable)iv.getBackground();
      aw.start();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just call aw.stop() before aw.start()

Comment: After hours trying to deal with this, I find the right answer right after posting the question. The worst thing is that... it's the second time it happens to me.

Comment: So now I don't know if I should wait more or less before posting a question :/

Comment: Thanks slipbull :) (Y)
I tried this solution and it worked for me. but i still don't understand why it fixed the problem!!
I mean it is not logical to call stop first then start !

Comment: @slipbull I needed to call aw.selectDrawable(0) as well to reset the AnimationDrawable completely, otherwise it would run for a second time and that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);
```

Comment: oneShot: true/false will either do it once or loop forever

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:oneShot="true" to
android:oneShot="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replay a one shot animation after previous animation finish you can do like

```
final AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
if (!animationDrawable.isRunning()) {

    int totalFrameDuration = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < animationDrawable.getNumberOfFrames(); i++) {
        totalFrameDuration += animationDrawable.getDuration(i);
    }

    animationDrawable.start();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animationDrawable.stop();
        }
    }, duration);
}
```